# How can I print a changing div using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I have a `div` of which I can control the color by changing its hexadecimal value, but how do I print it to be at whichever color I choose instead of the original color I had on the `div`?

**For example**: my `div` is *white*. I changed the color to *red* and I have a button that allows me to print that `div`, but it shows me that I'm printing a *white* `div` instead of a *red* one.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var gAutoPrint = true; // Tells whether to automatically call the print function

function printSpecial()
{
if (document.getElementById != null)
{
var html = '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n';

if (document.getElementsByTagName != null)
{
var headTags = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
if (headTags.length > 0)
html += headTags[0].innerHTML;
}

html += '\n</HE>\n<BODY>\n';

var printReadyElem = document.getElementById("printReady");

if (printReadyElem != null)
{
html += printReadyElem.innerHTML;
}
else
{
alert("Could not find the printReady function");
return;
}

html += '\n</BO>\n</HT>';

var printWin = window.open("","printSpecial");
printWin.document.open();
printWin.document.write(html);
printWin.document.close();
if (gAutoPrint)
printWin.print();
}
else
{
alert("The print ready feature is only available if you are using a browser. Please
update your browser.");
}
}

</script>
```

This is my button and selected `div`:

```
<div id="printReady"> 

div I want to print
</div>

<a href="javascript:void(printSpecial())" style="position:absolute">Print this Page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question, you can just add at the top of printSpecial() this line of code:

```
$('#printReady').css('background', '#ff0000');
```

A better way of controlling this kind of thing though would be to use a style.

```
<style>
   .ready {
     background: #ffffff;
   }

   .printing {
     background: #ff0000;
   }
</style>
```

Then you can use jQuery.addClass and jQuery.removeClass. That way you just change your CSS to whatever you want to have in both "states".

You then do this to change the style:

```
$('#printReady').removeClass('ready');
$('#printReady').addClass('printing');
```

And then in reverse when you want to change it back.

Answer (score 0):

Add a style

```
html += '<style>* { color: red }</style>';
```

for example

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var gAutoPrint = true; // Tells whether to automatically call the print function

function printSpecial() {
  if (document.getElementById == null) return false;
  var printReadyElem = document.getElementById("printReady");
  if (printReadyElem==null) {
    alert("Could not find the printReady function");
    return false;
  }

  var html = '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n';

  if (document.getElementsByTagName != null) {
    var headTags = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
    if (headTags.length > 0) html += headTags[0].innerHTML;
  }

  html += '<style>* { color: red }</style>';
  html += '\n</HEAD>\n<BODY>\n';
  html += printReadyElem.innerHTML;
  html += '\n</BODY>\n</HTML>';

  var printWin = window.open("","printSpecial");
  if (printWin) {
    printWin.document.write(html);
    printWin.document.close();
    if (gAutoPrint) {
      printWin.focus().print();
    }
  }    
  else {
    alert("The print ready feature is only available if you are using a browser that supports it and you have not blocked popups. Please update your browswer.");
  }
  return false;
}
</script>


this is my button and selected div

  <div id="printReady"> 

  div i want to print
  </div>

  <a href="#" onclick="return printSpecial()" style="position:absolute">Print this Page</a>
```